# Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED while creating cordova project

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm getting the CERT_UNTRUSTED error while creating a cordova project

```
C:\>cordova create kapsel_workspace com.example.myApp MyApp
Creating a new cordova project with name "MyApp" and id "com.example.myApp" at l
ocation "C:\kapsel_workspace"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1350:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:963:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
```

I have set the proxy for npm and I had got same error while installing cordova, i had used the following command and it had worked

```
C:\>npm config set strict-ssl false
```

But its not working for create command . Have i missed something ?

Comment: npm config set strict-ssl false should be the solution, but I am also not able to create the project with it.
@smath8 - have you found a solution for this??

Comment: @LohithKrishna - No, i finally created the project manually with the help of this link-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845056/how-to-install-cordova3-0-manually

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for you, I have the answer 7 years later. After running the line they mention in your post,

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I downloaded the latest version of NodeJS and after that I no longer had a problem creating a new cordova project.

I hope this answer helps you and others...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the question more carefully before answering. This does not answer the question, as the OP already stated in their question that they had tried your proposed solution and it did not work for them.