# How to install cordova(3.0) manually

Tags: cordova

I downloaded apache cordova 3.3.0. It has cordova-android sub folder , i unzipped it . how do i copy this to my android project? I cant find the jar file and the xml .
and also how to add plugin to this project manually?

I dont want command line approach. Because my company wont allow it to download .

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure using cordova without the cli will be very easy and maybe you should try phonegap build instead (nothing at all to download on your computer).

Anyway, let's see what we can do...

You do not say which platform you are targeting, so I'll try to explain for what I know : android.

### **First, the prerequisites**

You have to have on your computer and available in the path:

- java jdk (and set the JAVA_HOME env var)
- apache ant
- android sdk
- install the latest platform tools from the android sdk manager (as of cordova 3.3.0, is is API 19)
- eclipse with the adt plugin installed (or the eclipse included in the android sdk install)

Check full list in [the platform guide in the cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides).

### **Then, install cordova**

Then you download the cordova source zip from [the download page](http://cordova.apache.org/#download) and extract it somewhere in your hard drive (can be temp folder).

In the extracted folder, you will find one zip for each platform, so for android we will use cordova-android.zip.

Extract this folder somewhere in your user home folder and modify your path to include the `cordova-android\bin folder`.

Now you have access to cordova tools that you can run from command line (much like with the CLI) (if you're using windows, then use the .bat files):

- `check_reqs` : run this to check that every dependencies are found on your computer
- `android_sdk_version` : run this to check the android api installed (should return 19 for cordova 3.3 to work correctly)
- `update` : use this to update an existing project to the new version of cordova (so I guess you won't need this one for the moment)
- `create` : use this one to create a new cordova project. Check the arguments of [cordova create in the cli documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_create_the_app), create works the same, except you run `create` instead of `cordova create`.

### **Now you can create a project**

to create a new cordova project run the following command (remember, create.bat if you're on windows) :

```
create myapp com.mycompany.myapp MyApp
```

You've just created the MyApp application in the myapp folder.

### Import the project in eclipse

In eclipse, go in the new project wizard and select "Android project from existing code" and set the root directory at the root of the previously created project.

You should see two projects :

- MyApp : your application
- MyApp-CordovaLib : in cordova 3.3, the cordova core is no more in a jar but in this separate project.

Now you can use eclipse to run/debug the project or build release apk.

### Customise your project

- customise your html5 appp in the assets/www folder
- change android specific settings in the file AndroidManifest.xml (like autorisations for example)
- change cordova settings in the file res/xml/config.xml (like features for plugins)

### Add plugins

With cordova 3 you will need to install plugins for every API, so without plugins you will not be able to call any native API and be limited to HTML5 API.

Usually you install plugins using the cordova CLI, or plugman CLI (also need to be installed with npm), but here you will have to do everything manually.

As I'm running out of time, I'll cover this subject later, if you need it or if other people ask for it.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply and time.I followed your steps, But when I import my project into the ADT workspace I get error in MyApp: your Application. org.apache.cordova.* does not load.

Comment: I'm sorry , i got it working . I had to add the reference to cordova library which i had forgot. Thanks a ton :)

It would be helpful if u also throw some light on how to install plugins.